# Binding library warning `The method was removed because its name contains a dollar sign`

Tags: java, c#, kotlin, xamarin

I'm creating a binding library of a 3rd party sdk.

`java-resolution-report.log` file contains the following lines:

```
The method '[Method] android.os.Handler access$getHandlerOverride$cp()' was removed because its name contains a dollar sign.
The method '[Method] java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger access$getTHREAD_COUNT$cp()' was removed because its name contains a dollar sign.
The method '[Method] void access$setHandlerOverride$cp(android.os.Handler <set-?>)' was removed because its name contains a dollar sign.
The method '[Method] java.util.regex.Pattern access$getDELIMITERS$cp()' was removed because its name contains a dollar sign.
The method '[Method] java.util.regex.Pattern access$getFORMAT$cp()' was removed because its name contains a dollar sign.
The method '[Method] int access$boolToInt(boolean value)' was removed because its name contains a dollar sign.
The method '[Method] boolean access$intToBool(int value)' was removed because its name contains a dollar sign.
The method '[Method] java.util.regex.Pattern access$getPATTERN$cp()' was removed because its name contains a dollar sign.
The method '[Method] x.x.Version copy$default(x.x.Version p0, int p1, int p2, java.lang.Integer p3, int p4, java.lang.Object p5)' was removed because its name contains a dollar sign.
The method '[Method] javax.crypto.Cipher access$getCipher$p(x.x.EncryptionHelper.Companion $this)' was removed because its name contains a dollar sign.
The method '[Method] java.security.KeyStore access$getLoadedKeyStore$p(x.x.EncryptionHelper.Companion $this)' was removed because its name contains a dollar sign.
The method '[Method] byte[] access$generateRandomBytes(int length)' was removed because its name contains a dollar sign.
The method '[Method] javax.crypto.Cipher access$getRsaCipher$p()' was removed because its name contains a dollar sign.
The method '[Method] byte[] access$copyOf(byte[] data)' was removed because its name contains a dollar sign.
The method '[Method] x.x.EncryptionHelper access$createEncryptionHelper(android.content.Context context)' was removed because its name contains a dollar sign.
The method '[Method] byte[] access$base64StringToBytes(java.lang.String base64String)' was removed because its name contains a dollar sign.
The method '[Method] java.lang.String access$bytesToBase64String(byte[] bytes)' was removed because its name contains a dollar sign.
```

these methods seem to be auto-generated as they are written in `Kotlin`.

For example `access$getLoadedKeyStore$p` is an access getter for the property `loadedKeyStore`:

```
public companion object {
    private final val cipher: javax.crypto.Cipher /* compiled code */

    private final val loadedKeyStore: java.security.KeyStore /* compiled code */
}
```

`Xamarin.Kotlin.StdLib` is installed.

How can I rename these methods if they are auto-generated?

Comment: Why are the methods even removed in the first place? A dollar sign in a method name is perfectly valid, and is used all around the place. Even java generates methods with dollar signs in them, with lambdas, or class names with dollar signs in them, for inner classes. Removing those is entirely nonsensical.

Comment: Those are warning messages and not errors.  When referencing from a different language you will need to reference the variables without the dollar sign.

Comment: These methods were removed by the Binding Library translation engine, and are required by the 3rd party sdk to operate. I need to figure out how to prevent that from happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there doesn't seem to be a way to resolve these errors.

Therefore I changed my approach to consume the third party SDK that incorporates Kotlin:

- Write a Java wrapper module that consumes the SDK and provides an interface that will be embedded along with the wrapper classes.
- Add the `.arr` of the wrapper with build action `LibraryProjectZip`
- Add the relevant `.jar` files with build action `EmbeddedReferenceJar`
- Consume the wrapper in Xamarin by writing a class that inherits `Java.Lang.Object` and implements the interface

That way only the wrapper is bound and the SDK is available at runtime.

The warnings should disappear, along with any need to use `Metadata.xml`

Comment: You had opened a support ticket on Microsoft about this if i'm not wrong? Is this what they told you? There's no away to rename generated accessor methods using Metadata?

Comment: Adding this in case someone else has the same issue as me - in my case those were just warnings that seemingly have no effect right now to the behavior of the third party SDK in use. The way I solved my issue: I went back to the Bindings project for one of the assemblies and while tinkering with the Metadata due to Kotlin warnings, I remembered I installed "**Xamarin.Kotlin.StdLib**" NuGet. I tried this, and it resolved my missing methods exceptions.

Comment: @iBobb I did open a support ticket on Microsoft, and first was referred to the relevant documentation. Unfortunately I was not able to resolve these warnings with the provided links. I then suggested using a wrapper module that will call the 3rd party SDK methods, and Xamarin will consume only the wrapper instead. That way the bindings will only be generated for the wrapper, and not for the SDK, so the warnings should disappear. I was referred to https://youtu.be/lJofHxTd44Q?t=1243 which suggests this approach is preferred.

Comment: I had to find and download the dependencies myself (the hard way, via exceptions), but at least with this method I was sure the 3rd party SDK is used natively, and it saved me a few days of fighting with the Metadata.xml file syntax